# How to access custom cell textfield values Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created a custom tableViewCell class for a prototype cells which is holding a text field. Inside ThirteenthViewController, I would like to reference the tableViewCell class so that I can access its `doorTextField` property in order to assign to it data retrieved from UserDefaults. How can I do this?

```
class ThirteenthViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITextFieldDelegate  {

var options = [
Item(name:"Doorman",selected: false),
Item(name:"Lockbox",selected: false),
Item(name:"Hidden-Key",selected: false),
Item(name:"Other",selected: false)
]
    let noteCell:NotesFieldUITableViewCell! = nil


@IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: Any) {
     //save the value of textfield when button is touched
     UserDefaults.standard.set(noteCell.doorTextField.text, forKey: textKey)

    //if doorTextField is not empty assign value to FullData
    guard let text = noteCell.doorTextField.text, text.isEmpty else {
        FullData.finalEntryInstructions = noteCell.doorTextField.text!
               return
      }
     FullData.finalEntryInstructions = "No"
 }


  override func viewDidLoad() {
     let index:IndexPath = IndexPath(row:4,section:0)
      let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: index) as! NotesFieldUITableViewCell
        self.tableView.delegate = self
          self.tableView.dataSource = self
           cell.doorTextField.delegate = self
}

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return options.count
 }


 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


 // configure the cell
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    -> UITableViewCell     {

        if indexPath.row < 3 {
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!
            cell.textLabel?.text = options[indexPath.row].name
              return cell
           } else {
       let othercell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textField") as! NotesFieldUITableViewCell
            othercell.doorTextField.placeholder = "some text"
               return othercell
     }
   }
}//end of class



  class NotesFieldUITableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
     @IBOutlet weak var doorTextField: UITextField!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
    }
  override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
      super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to access the `UITextField` in your cell, you need to know which row of the `UITableView` contains your cell. In your case, I believe the row is always the 4th one. So, you can create an IndexPath for the row and then, you can simply do something like this:

```
let ndx = IndexPath(row:3, section: 0)
let cell = table.cellForRow(at:ndx) as! NotesFieldUITableViewCell
let txt = cell.doorTextField.text
```

The above might not be totally syntactically correct since I didn't check for syntax, but I'm sure you can take it from there, right?

However, do note that in order for the above to work, the last row (row 4) has to be always visible. If you try to fetch rows which are not visible, you do run into issues with accessing them since `UITableView` reuses cells and instantiates cells for the visible rows of data.

Also, if you simply want to get the text that the user types and text input ends when they tap "Enter", you can always simply bypass accessing the table row at all and add a `UITextFieldDelegate` to your custom cell to send a notification out with the entered text so that you can listen for the notification and take some action.

But, as I mentioned above, this all depends on how you have things set up and what you are trying to achieve :)

**Update:**

Based on further information, it appears as if you want to do something with the text value when the `nextButton` method is called. If so, the following should (theoretically) do what you want:

```
@IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: Any) {
    // Get the cell
    let ndx = IndexPath(row:4, section: 0)
    let cell = table.cellForRow(at:ndx) as! NotesFieldUITableViewCell
    //save the value of textfield when button is touched
    UserDefaults.standard.set(cell.doorTextField.text, forKey: textKey)

    //if doorTextField is not empty assign value to FullData
    guard let text = cell.doorTextField.text, text.isEmpty else {
        FullData.finalEntryInstructions = cell.doorTextField.text!
               return
      }
     FullData.finalEntryInstructions = "No"
}
```

Comment: I have update my question. The table view will always have 5 rows (counting from 1, the items in options array + 1 more row for the textField). What happens in the small Iphone iphone screens if the row is covered or if users scrolls the table?

Comment: That's why I mentioned using a UITextFieldDelegate if you only want the data entry from the user. It depends on when you want to use the data from the last row. For example, if you use the data as soon as they enter it, then the row should be visible. But if you want to save the entered data and take action later, then you probably want to get the value as soon as they enter it and persist it for later use. Does that make sense?

Comment: I want to use the data entry from the user when nextButton is tapped. I need to know when the textField is edited as I am lifting nextButton above the keyboard when textField is edited and pin it to the bottom of the view when return is tapped.

Comment: OK, in that case, the above code should work since the nextButton will be tapped immediately after the user is done editing and so the last row will still be visible. Only thing you'll have to change is the index for the row since now you'll have 5 rows. Try the code and let me know if you run into any issues ...

Comment: I get error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping on line 64. I put all code in a gist. https://gist.github.com/bibscy/f5f1c70f83441dd30a364e022e0904b3

Comment: Why would you want to run that code in `viewDidLoad`? At that point, the table view has probably not even loaded. Where you want to put the code is actually in the `nextButton` method. Since you don't have a reference to `noteCell` set anywhere, that code would probably fail. Instead, put the code I provided and get the text field value there. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: If I set `cell.doorTextField.delegate = self` in nextButton, I will never be able to load the data from user defaults and assign it to doorTextField when ViewWillAppear

Comment: No, no, not set the text delegate - the other code, to get the cell based on the indexPath :)

Comment: I've edited my answer above to show you what needs to be done. If you go this route and it works, then you don't need the `UITextFieldDelegate` at all ...

Comment: It won't work... `let cell = table.cellForRow(at:ndx) as! NotesFieldUITableViewCell` , cell is valid only inside nextButton. However, even if I assign `cell` to a global variable, I will still not be able to load the data from UserDefaults and assign it to the textfield because `cell` will be create only when `nextButton` is tapped. If button is not tapped, `let ndx` and `let cell` will not exist.

Comment: Do not assign cells to variables. That is not a good practice. Instead, take the value from the text field and store it in a variable. As far as I can tell, the value won't change again till `nextButton` is tapped again, correct? I don't understand the rest of what you said, but if you want to continue this in a chat, do start one since this comment thread is getting very long :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139114/discussion-between-bibscy-and-fahim).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a tag for the doorTextField (for instance 111)
Now you can retrieve the value.

```
@IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: Any) {
//save the value of textfield when button is touched
guard let textField = self.tableViewview.viewWithTag(111) as! UITextField? else { return }
prit(textField.text)

.....
```

}

Comment: That would work if the cell is visible, but if it is not visible, then the cell would not be instantiated and so you won't be able to access the text field via tag.

Comment: The cell is subview on the same class view controller and the array has only 4 items to display. The cell is not visible?? Can you explain?

Comment: I believe it's 4 + the new cell. But I agree, it *should* still be visible as long as the cells are thin enough. But the OP was worried about the last cell not showing up on a smaller screen iPhone. Plus, if the cells were to be made wide for some reason (big images, perhaps) the last row could possibly not show. So it might be better to have a solution which can work under all conditions, don't you agree?